# Collation list h2 database

Tags: android, database, internationalization, collation, h2

I am trying to set the collation of a new H2 Database over an Android device, and I have two doubts:

If I don't specify the collation name of the database with collation is used for it.

Where I can find a list of the differents collations that exists and support H2?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, String.compareTo is used (lexicographic ordering - see the the Android documentation for details).

You can use set the collator using [set collation](http://h2database.com/html/commands.html#set_collation) (see docs for details). One of the `new Locale(...)` constructors is used depending on how the collation is set. You would need to check what languages / countries / variants are supported in the Android documentation.